# Module Name Error

Tags: python-2.7, module

```
>>> import EpicMatrix

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import EpicMatrix
ImportError: No module named EpicMatrix
>>>
```

I have created this module and saved it as .py file but still python is not able to recognise it

Comment: Maybe it is not your case, but... Could you provide a tree structure of your files and explain from which one the import is made? If EpicMatrix.py file is contained in a subfolder with no `__init__.py` file on it, that might be the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the directory containing this file to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

PYTHONPATH is a list of directories to look at to load modules from.  If the module isn't in one of the directories in PYTHONPATH then python won't be able to find it.  That is what's happening here.